# Swap and Sun, custom test cases are passed, but inbuilt having runtime error, why?

Tags: python, arrays, list, runtime-error

You have an identity permutation of N integers as an array initially. In this task, you have to perform operations on the array and report the sum of the elements of the array after each operation.  The M operations consist of an integer op in each line.  If the array contains op, swap the first and last elements in the array.
Else, remove the last element of the array and push op to the end of the array.
Here's my code in python :

```
l = raw_input().split(" ")
N=int(l[0])
M=int(l[1])
if(N>=2 and M>=2):
    s=0
    l1=[i for i in range(1,N+1)]
    while(M!=0):
        s=0
        op=int(input())
        if(op not in l1):
            l1.pop()
            l1.append(op)
            for i in l1:
                s+=i
            print(s)
        else:
            l1[0],l1[N-1]=l1[N-1],l1[0]
            for i in l1:
                s+=i
            print(s)
        M-=1
```

I am getting a run time error for almost every case. But with every custom input, this runs. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: IT just simply says runtime error, nothing else mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Please state the format of the input given for the test cases. I think the error occurred because of this line `op=int(input())` , it is not receiving any input.